# Django: kwargs of ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have to models called `Event` and `Registration`. Here you can see my `admin.py`:

```
    class RegistrationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Registration
    form = RegistrationForm # inherits from ModelForm

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventForm

    inlines = [RegistrationInline]
```

In my `RegistrationForm` I have this here because I need the pk of the Event:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.event = kwargs.get('instance').event # In my Registration model "Event" is a ForeignKey
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I go in my Admin and go to a Event, the output of `kwargs` is:

```
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-0', 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>, 'use_required_attribute': False, 'instance': <Registration: 1>}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-1', 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>, 'use_required_attribute': False, 'instance': <Registration: 2>}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-2', 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>, 'use_required_attribute': False, 'instance': <Registration: 3>}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-3', 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>, 'use_required_attribute': False, 'instance': <Registration: 4>}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-__prefix__', 'empty_permitted': True, 'use_required_attribute': False}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-__prefix__', 'empty_permitted': True, 'use_required_attribute': False}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'registration_set-__prefix__', 'empty_permitted': True, 'use_required_attribute': False}
```

My problem are the last three lines. Becuase there is no `instance` my approach does not work. How can I remove those three lines or what do those three lines mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here; those are just the three extra blank forms Django adds by default in a formset. You should just check that the parameter is passed:

```
instance = kwargs.get('instance')
if instance is not None:
    self.event = instance.event
```